# View contents of ADFS claims in Glimpse?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

So i installed the glimpse (http://getglimpse.com/) nuget package in my mvc3 app.  Wow neat tool.  But has anyone figured out how to inspect adfs claims in glimplse?  I can see the "AUTH_USER" on the server tab, but doesn't have any of the claims or roles that i get shipped from adfs.  If its not supported out of the box maybe ill write a plugin.

**Solution:**
I wrote a plugin that seems to work great.  Thanks for the help and the great product Nik!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Glimpse.AspNet.Extensions;
using Glimpse.Core.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims;

namespace ADFSClaimsPlugin
{
    public class ADFSClaimsInspector : TabBase
    {
        public override object GetData(ITabContext context)
        {
            var res = new List<string[]> { new[] { "Subject", "Type", "Value", "Value Type", "Issuer", "Original Issuer" } };
            var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();

            var iPrincipal = (IClaimsPrincipal)httpContext.User;
            var identity = (IClaimsIdentity)iPrincipal.Identity;

            res.AddRange(identity.Claims.Select(c => new[] {  c.Subject==null?string.Empty:c.Subject.ToString(),c.ClaimType, 
                c.Value, c.ValueType, c.Issuer ,c.OriginalIssuer }));

            return res;
        }

        public override string Name
        {
            get { return "Claim Data"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this stuff, but [Maarten Balliauw](https://twitter.com/maartenballiauw) created [a Window Identity Foundation plugin](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/05/10/A-Glimpse-at-Windows-Identity-Foundation-claims.aspx) awhile back which showed off claims tokens - it may be a good starting point for you.

His plugin is a bit out of date (it will no longer work with Glimpse 1.0+), but it should be easy to update and package based on the [custom tab documentation](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Custom-Tabs).

I'm also more than happy to help you out. You can [contact me on Twitter](https://twitter.com/nikmd23).

Comment: Wow, got a response from a project co-founder after ~1hour!?!?!  Thanks for the links to the documentation.  I'll hopefully have time to work on this tomorrow, looks like its gonna be really simple to create a tab!  Glad i heard of this project on .Net Rocks.

Comment: Thanks for the help, plugin works well.  I can publish to Nuget if you think it would help someone else.

Comment: I do! Ping [me on Twitter](https://twitter.com/nikmd23) when you do and I'll include it in [the Glimpse Extension Gallery feed](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2013/03/29/glimpse-extensions-gallery/).